# Can editing the UEFI improve stability or performance?

Tags: uefi

While looking into something else sort of unrelated, I stumbled in the bios modding community, but their explanations are mostly opaque, frequently giving no guides (what they do is that they let people request custom bios, and experienced modders make the new custom bios and give it to the person that requested it).

Seemly the most popular mods are:

- Replace AHCI.
- Move Windows OEM install between motherboards.
- "Fix" shoddily made ACPI device tables.
- Replace RAID drivers.
- Replace some other drivers.
- Replace AMI filesystem drivers with Intel's ones.
- Add operating system selector and bootloader.

I honestly have no idea what most of these are for (specially the lots of AHCI mods...), so I am wondering, why these people are doing this? Does it actually increase performance or stability? What UEFI drivers affect beside the boot process?

Comment: I will be honest, I don't need you to admit to anything, I wish you Good Luck on modifying your UEFI firmware to acomplsh those changes you listed.  Only one of things you mentioned is even a function of the firmware itself, everything else, would be the responsability of the OS.  *Even then I could argue, the way I personally read the statement, I thought you were talking about the OS filesystem drivers.*  I will be removing my previous two comments, reporting the other comments as obsolete, and just moving on.  *Can a moderator delete this comment once that happens?*

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with the firmware modifications that float around; however, as a general rule they're meant to fix problems in the boot process or improve OS reliability. For instance, some EFIs have known-flaky FAT drivers that can cause boot loaders to malfunction. Fixing ACPI tables can improve the reliability of device detection in a booted OS. Recent versions of Windows store license keys in the firmware, so modifying those may be helpful if you replace your motherboard (but I'm speculating on this one). I recommend asking the sources for why specific modifications are made.